# What is a constant reference? (not a reference to a constant)

Tags: c++, reference, constants

Why do constant references not behave the same way as constant pointers, so that I can actually change the object they are pointing to? They really seem like another plain variable declaration. Why would I ever use them?

This is a short example that I run which compiles and runs with no errors:

```
int main (){
    int i=0;
    int y=1;    
    int&const icr=i;
    icr=y;          // Can change the object it is pointing to so it's not like a const pointer...
    icr=99;         // Can assign another value but the value is not assigned to y...
    int x=9;
    icr=x;
    cout<<"icr: "<<icr<<", y:"<<y<<endl; 
}
```

Comment: Look at `i` before and after `icr=y;`.

Comment: see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.7

Comment: check the value of x at the end . its 9 . since icr which refers to i has been changed to 9.

Comment: This doesn't compile!! `int&const icr=i;` is wrong.

Comment: Since this has just bubbled to the top (and both are old), I'm just going to point out that this is duplicated by the better-titled [_Can we reassign the reference_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9293674/212858]) question.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The clearest answer.
**[Does “X& const x” make any sense?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-ref-nonsense)**

> **No, it is nonsense**
>
> To find out what the above declaration means, read it right-to-left:
> “x is a const reference to a X”. But that is redundant — references
> are always const, in the sense that you can never reseat a reference
> to make it refer to a different object. Never. With or without the
> const.
>
> In other words, “X& const x” is functionally equivalent to “X& x”.
> Since you’re gaining nothing by adding the const after the &, you
> shouldn’t add it: it will confuse people — the const will make some
> people think that the X is const, as if you had said “const X& x”.

Comment: `X& const x` is ill-formed, this is a mistake in the FAQ

Answer (score 54):

The statement `icr=y;` does not make the reference refer to `y`; it assigns the value of `y` to the variable that `icr` refers to, `i`.

References are inherently `const`, that is you can't change what they refer to. There are '`const` references' which are really 'references to `const`', that is you can't change the value of the object they refer to. They are declared `const int&` or `int const&` rather than `int& const` though.

Comment: So a reference to a const can also be seen as a constant reference to a const? That makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: @Dasaru:
Yes, it can, but a reference to non-const can also be seen as a constant reference to non-const, as the reference itself is always const, independently from if it references a const or not.

Answer (score 30):

**What is a constant reference (not a reference to a constant)**
A **Constant Reference** is actually a **Reference to a Constant**.

A constant reference/ Reference to a constant is denoted by:

```
int const &i = j; //or Alternatively
const int &i = j;
i = 1;            //Compilation Error
```

It basically means, you cannot modify the value of type object to which the Reference Refers.
**For Example:**
Trying to modify value(assign `1`) of variable `j` through const reference, `i` will results in error:

> assignment of read-only reference ‘i’

---

```
icr=y;          // Can change the object it is pointing to so it's not like a const pointer...
icr=99;
```

Doesn't change the reference, it **assigns** the value of the type to which the reference refers.
References cannot be made to refer any other variable than the one they are bound to at Initialization.

First statement **assigns** the value `y` to `i`
Second statement **assigns** the value `99` to `i`

Comment: How & why statement like const int& a=3; valid?

Comment: Wait, `const Type&` is equivalent to `Type const&`?

Comment: While instructive with regard to the interaction between `const` and `&`, this answer does not quite address the question. `int const &` is not the same as `int & const` as present in the question. The latter is not even well-formed and won't compile (it would mean the non-sensical "constant reference" as described in the accepted answer). This answer is talking about a "reference to a constant", which is something else and well-formed.

Comment: @Tyler: yes. Same for `const Type*` and `Type const*`. The latter is not as common but considered by some people to be better since you can understand it by simply reading it right-to-left: "a pointer to a constant of type Type".

Answer (score 6):

This code is ill-formed:

```
int&const icr=i;
```

Reference: C++17 [dcl.ref]/1:

> Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced
>   through the use of a *typedef-name* or *decltype-specifier*, in which case the cv-qualifiers are ignored.

This rule has been present in all standardized versions of C++. Because the code is ill-formed:

- you should not use it, and
- there is no associated behaviour.

The compiler should reject the program; and if it doesn't, the executable's behaviour is completely undefined.

NB: Not sure how none of the other answers mentioned this yet... nobody's got access to a compiler?

Comment: Damn! Burn! But you're right - even I was wondering the same. When I wrote cv-qualified reference, compiled complained that 'error: ‘const’ qualifiers cannot be applied to ‘int&’' which makes complete sense. But I wonder since OP has compiled this code before so many years, may be in traditional standards (C98, C++03) it was allowed and ignored?

Comment: @ZoomIn there have been various compilers over the years that allow non-standard code

Answer (score 4):

By "constant reference" I am guessing you really mean "reference to constant data". Pointers on the other hand, can be a constant pointer (the pointer itself is constant, not the data it points to), a pointer to constant data, or both.

Comment: The sample code actually refers to a constant reference (`int & const icr = i;`) not a reference to a constant.

Comment: I assumed the poster wasn't clear because of where the const was placed in the code.

Answer (score 3):

As it mentioned in another answers, a reference is inherently const.

```
int &ref = obj;
```

Once you initialized a reference with an object, you can't unbound this reference with its object  it refers to. A reference works just like an alias.

When you declare a  `const` reference, it is nothing but a reference which refers to a const object.

```
const int &ref = obj;
```

The declarative sentences above like  `const` and `int` is determining the available features of the object which will be referenced by the reference. To be more clear, I want to show you the `pointer` equivalent of a `const` reference;

```
const int *const ptr = &obj;
```

So the above line of code is equivalent to a `const` reference in its working way. **Additionally**, there is a one last point which I want to mention;

> A reference must be initialized only with an object

So when you do this, you are going to get an error;

```
int  &r = 0; // Error: a nonconst reference cannot be initialized to a literal
```

This rule has one exception. If the reference is declared as const, then you can initialize it with literals as well;

```
const int  &r = 0; // a valid approach
```

Answer (score 0):

First I think `int&const icr=i;` is just `int& icr = i`, Modifier 'const' makes no sense(It just means you cannot make the reference refer to other variable).

```
const int x = 10;
// int& const y = x; // Compiler error here
```

Second, constant reference just means you cannot change the value of variable through reference.

```
const int x = 10;
const int& y = x;
//y = 20; // Compiler error here
```

Third, Constant references can bind right-value. Compiler will create a temp variable to bind the reference.

```
float x = 10;
const int& y = x;
const int& z = y + 10;
cout << (long long)&x << endl; //print 348791766212
cout << (long long)&y << endl; //print 348791766276
cout << (long long)&z << endl; //print 348791766340
```