# Can we reassign the reference in C++?

Tags: c++, reference

I have read everywhere that a reference has to be initialized then and there and can't be re-initialized again.

To test my understanding, I have written the following small program. It seems as if I have actually succeeded in reassigning a reference. Can someone explain to me what is actually going on in my program?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 5, j = 9;

    int &ri = i;
    cout << " ri is : " << ri  <<"\n";

    i = 10;
    cout << " ri is : " << ri  << "\n";

    ri = j; // >>> Is this not reassigning the reference? <<<
    cout << " ri is : " << ri  <<"\n";

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles fine and the output is as I expect:

```
ri is : 5
ri is : 10
ri is : 9
```

Comment: I am sure eventually c++ will add reference reassignment as a feature. For now, use pointers.

Comment: C++ added [std::reference_wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) in C++11.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

> `ri = j; // >>> Is this not reassigning the reference? <<<`

No, `ri` is still a reference to `i` - you can prove this by printing `&ri` and `&i` and seeing they're the same address.

What you did is modify `i` *through* the reference `ri`. Print `i` after, and you'll see this.

Also, for comparison, if you create a `const int &cri = i;` it won't let you assign to that.

Comment: Why is `const int &cri = i` not allowed? On which line you can't write that? Cause for me compiler allows to insert such line in any place. Apart from that, it's a clear and concise answer!

Comment: I didn't say that isn't allowed - as you observed, taking a const ref to a non-const variable is fine. I said it _won't let you assign to that_, meaning you can't change the original variable via a const ref, like OP did with `ri`.

Comment: I "cri" everytime

Answer (score 20):

> It seems as if I have actually succeeded in reassigning a reference.
>   Is that true?

**No**, you haven't. You are actually reassigning the value, and you are not rebinding the reference.

In your example, when you do `int &ri = i;`, `ri` is bound to `i` for its lifetime. When you do `ri = j;`, you are simply assigning the value of `j` to `ri`. `ri` still remains a reference to `i`! And it results in the same outcome as if you had instead written `i = j;`

If you understand pointers well, then always think of the reference as an analogical interpretation of `T* const` where `T` is any type.

Answer (score 6):

When you assign something to a reference you actually assign the value to the object the reference is bound to. So this:

```
ri=j;
```

has the same effect as

```
i = j;
```

would have because `ri` is bound to `i`. So any action on `ri` is executed on `i`.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot "reseat" a reference(https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#reseating-refs).

One useful mantra with references in C++ is that the references *are* the object they refer to. Any change you make to it *is* to make change to what ever they refer to. Using the mantra you can probably see what's happening when you do `ri = j`, i now *is* j.

Answer (score 3):

You are not reassigning the reference when executing `ri = j;`. You're actually assigning `j` to `i`. Try printing `i` after the line and you'll see that `i` changed value.

Answer (score 2):

OP asked for altering the referenced object through assignment to the reference and was very correctly told that this changed the reference object, not the reference.
Now I did a more poignant attempt at really changing the reference and found potentially nasty stuff.
First the code. It attempts to reassign to the reference var a newly created object, then alters the reference aka referenced object, finds that this is not reflected in the apparently referenced objects and concludes that we may have a case of a dangling pointer in C++. Sorry for the hastily composed code.

```
using namespace std;
vector<int>myints;

auto &i = myints.emplace_back();   // allocate and reference new int in vector
auto myintsaddr = &myints; auto myintfrontaddr = &myints.front(); // for future reference
i = 1;                             // assign a value to the new int through reference
cout << hex << "address of i: 0x" << &i << " equals " << "address of 
myints.back(): 0x" << &myints.back() << '.' << endl;  // check reference as expected
i = myints.emplace_back();     // allocate new int in vector and assign to old reference variable
i = 2;                         // give another value to i
cout << "i=" << i << ", myints={" << myints[0] << ", "<< myints[1] << '}' << endl; // any change to potentially referenced objects?
cout << hex << "&i: 0x" << &i << " unequal to " << "&myints.back(): 0x" << &myints.back() << " as well as &myints.front(): 0x" << &myints.front() << endl;
cout << "Myints " << (myintsaddr== &myints?"not ":"") << "relocated from " << myintsaddr << " to " << &myints << endl;
cout << "Myints front() " << (myintfrontaddr == &myints.front() ? "not " : "") << "relocated from " << myintfrontaddr << " to " << &myints.front() << endl;
```

Output:

```
address of i: 0x0063C1A0 equals address of myints.back(): 0x0063C1A0.
i=2, myints={1, 0}
&i: 0x0063C1A0 unequal to &myints.back(): 0x0063F00C as well as &myints.front(): 0x0063F008
Myints not relocated from 0039FE48 to 0039FE48
Myints front() relocated from 0063C1A0 to 0063F008
```

Conclusion: at least in my case (VS2017) the reference has kept the exact same address in memory, but the referenced values (part of the vector) have been reallocated elsewhere. Reference i may be dangling.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words,

`ri = j;` <- You are writing value of j in x(ri) memory. And ri will still hold or point to x.