# Reference variable equals another reference variable?

Tags: c++

Consider the following:

```
int someA = 1;
int someB = 2;

int &a = someA;
int &b = someB;

a = b;   // what happens here?
```

What's happening here with the references?  Just curious.

Comment: There is no compile error here.  (See e.g. http://ideone.com/RR4vcz)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293674/can-we-reassign-the-reference-in-c to understand what you have done here.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: this code is UB since it uses names reserved for implementations. :)

Comment: Also read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/14065 as `_A` is reserved.

Comment: Don't use names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_A`) or that have two consecutive underscores. They are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Don't use identifiers beginning with an underscore. If he had used `_a` in this context it would have been just as invalid as we are in global scope. Remembering when you can and can't use '_' at the beginning is complex and often misquoted. So a simple rule is never use it.

Comment: @LokiAstari - good point, although there is no valid context here. `<g>`

Comment: Sorry I rephrased the question since I feel this has become a bit off-topic.  Sorry.

Comment: @PeteBecker: There was before the question was re-phrased. The only way to get the compiler error was to put a statement outside a function (thus in global scope).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having two reference variables equal to each other is in itself not an error. It may be confusing. However, what your code does is not setting a reference to another reference, it's altering the value of `_A` from `1` to `2`, which is what's in `_B`.

You can ONLY set a reference ONCE [where it is initialized]. Once it's been initialized, it will simply become an alias for the original variable.

You could do this:

```
int &a = _A;
int &b = _A;
```

and

```
a = b;
```

would store the value `1` into `_A`, which already has the value `1`.

Comment: The answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There is no error here, but I think I may know what you're confused about.  The reference won't be reassigned, however the value of what it is referencing is reassigned.

So when you do `a = b;` you're essentially saying this: `_A = _B`, because a reference is an alias.

A reference can never be reassigned like a pointer can.

A reference can also never be null.

Answer (score 2):

You can not have statements outside a function.

```
a = b;   //compile error?
```

That is a statement so must be in a function:

```
int _A = 1;
int _B = 2;

int &a = _A;
int &b = _B;

int main()
{
   a = b;   //compile error? No. Now it compiles.

   // As 'a' and 'b' are references.
   // This means they are just another name for an already existing variable
   // ie they are alias
   //
   // It means that it is equivalent to using the original values.
   //
   // Thus it is equivalent too:
   _A = _B;
}
```

Now it compiles.

Comment: I rephrased the question.  This is not the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Placeable: Then you should have asked a new question!

Comment: The question is the same.  Syntax and the comment has changed.

Comment: Okay, clarified then?

I wanted to ask what would happen if I assigned a reference to another reference.

Like:
int &a = 3;
int &b = 5;

a = b;

Comment: @Placeable: Yes. And that is a **DIFFERENT** question to why is there a `compiler error`. You can still read the original question.