# understanding references in c++

Tags: c++, reference

I have the following code:

```
int main() {
    int x = 3;
    int &ref = x;
    int &ref2 = ref;
    ref = 100;
    std::cout <<ref;
    std::cout <<ref2;
    return 0;
}
```

This print out `100` and `100`. I find it confusing. My understanding was that both `ref` and `ref2` are references to the underlying object (`x=3`). We then change the value of `ref`. 
As such, I expected `100` and `3`.

Comment: `x`, `ref` and `ref2` all refer to the same `int`, why do you expect it to print who different values?

Comment: in your code, the `x` variable will be also `100`

Comment: You only have one integer, `x`. You have two references to the same integer object. You cannot change the "value of `ref`", because references don't _have_ values. You can only change the value of the object it refers to, which is `x`.

Answer (score 6):

You don't ever change the *value* of `ref` (the language does not let you *rebind* a reference). In fact, this is why you need to use [reference initialisation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization) when you create a reference: you can't write `int &ref; ref = x;` for example.

The statement `ref = 100;` changes the value of the object to which the reference is bound.

Hence the output of `x`, `ref`, and `ref2` are identical.

Answer (score 5):

> My understanding was that both ref and ref2 are references to the underlying object (x=3)

Yes.

Well, they're both references to `x`, whose *initial* value is `3`.
Essentially you have a single integer object, which you can refer to by the names any of the names `x`, `ref` or `ref2`.

> We then change the value of ref

No, you're contradicting yourself.

Objects have values. References like `ref` are not objects, but references to objects, and they don't *have* a value of their own to change.

You said that `ref` is a reference, which is true - it is a reference to an object of type int, which can take a value, and whose value is changed when you write `ref = 100`. The names `x`, `ref` and `ref2` still refer to the same integer object afterwards, but now its value is `100` instead of `3`.

You cannot *reseat* a reference (make it refer to a different object), and a reference does not have a value to change. It refers to an object, whose value may be changed via the reference.

---

NB. I don't think this question is quite a duplicate of [*Can we reassign the reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9293674/212858), even though it contains some of the same misunderstanding.