# How to expose a reference variable in a header?

Tags: c++, reference, header-files

I'm trying to create a reference variable `cParamIDsByAge` to one side of a `boost::bimap` for convenience (MVCE):

### Attempt #1

**code.h**

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>

typedef boost::bimap <int, int> ParamIDs;
extern const ParamIDs cParamIDs;
extern auto &cParamIDsByAge = cParamIDs.left;
```

**code.cpp**

```
#include "code.h"

// In my code this inits the variable with some data via a function.
const ParamIDs cParamIDs {};
auto &cParamIDsByAge = cParamIDs.left;
```

The compiler complains:

```
code.h:5:14: warning: ‘cParamIDsByAge’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
extern auto &cParamIDsByAge = cParamIDs.left;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
code.cpp:4:7: error: conflicting declaration ‘auto& cParamIDsByAge’
auto &cParamIDsByAge = cParamIDs.left;
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from code.cpp:1:0:
code.h:5:14: note: previous declaration as ‘const boost::bimaps::views::map_view<boost::bimaps::relation::member_at::left, boost::bimaps::detail::bimap_core<int, int, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na> >& cParamIDsByAge’
extern auto &cParamIDsByAge = cParamIDs.left;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

---

### Attempt #2

Then I tried defining the reference `cParamIDsByAge` in the header directly:

**code.h**

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>

typedef boost::bimap <int, int> ParamIDs;
extern const ParamIDs cParamIDs;
auto &cParamIDsByAge = cParamIDs.left;
```

**code.cpp**

```
#include "code.h"

const ParamIDs cParamIDs {};
```

But that complained about:

```
error: multiple definitions of cParamIDsByAge
```

---

### Attempt #3

I don't initialized the reference in the header:

**code.h**

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>

typedef boost::bimap <int, int> ParamIDs;
extern const ParamIDs cParamIDs;
extern const auto &cParamIDsByAge;
```

**code.cpp**

```
#include "code.h"
const ParamIDs cParamIDs {};
auto &cParamIDsByAge = cParamIDs.left;
```

Compiler complains about header file:

```
error: declaration of ‘const auto& cParamIDsByAge’ has no initializer
```

Comment: You can't initialize a variable twice. (It follows that you can't use `auto` in the header)

Comment: @M.M OK, but a reference var must be initialized. The best way I can think of is what I did in Attempt #2, and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message `code.h:5:14: warning: ‘cParamIDsByAge’ initialized and declared ‘extern’` is pretty straightforward:   in C++, variables declared as `extern` may not have an initializer. (In other words, `extern` may only appear in declarations, not definitions).

Sample usage might be:

```
extern int &foo;

// ... cpp file

int bar;
int &foo = bar;
```

---

To do this in your code, there is another issue in that you need to replace `int` with the type of `boost::bimap::left`. You can't use `auto` in the `extern` declaration because there is no initializer to deduce from.

`boost::bimap` happens to define this as a typedef so the solution is straightforward:

```
extern ParamIDs::left_map const &x;

// ... in cpp

const ParamIDs c{};
ParamIDs::left_map const &x = c.left;
```

If that typedef didn't exist then you could still do it using `declval` and `decltype`.

Note 1: I think the standard is unclear on whether `auto const &x = c.left;` should work here, but gcc and clang both reject it.

Comment: That compiles, thank you! I understand what the problems were now. PS: I read that references are implicitely `const`, so there is no need for the `const` keyword.

Comment: references are not implicitly const, you probably read someone who was mixed up about the difference between references and pointers

Comment: It's not the reference that is const, it's the object that it references. The reference itself cannot be modified once initialized, so in that sense yes, it is implicitly const. To declare a reference constant explicitly, you would have to write something like `int bar; int & const foo=bar;`, but this code is ill-formed and there is no associated behaviour. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52144646/4944216) elsewhere.

Comment: @il--ya `const` is a keyword, things are only `const` if they are qualified as such. It doesn't automatically mean anything that's not modifiable. Also, non-const references can be modified (this means modifying the object that the reference refers to). I think you mean to say that references cannot be rebound to different objects once they have been initialized but this is nothing to do with `const` or constantness.

Comment: Under the hood reference is effectively treated as a dereferenced const pointer, and "bounding" is effectively assigning an initial value to this pointer. It actually can be modified (thus rebound), using some implementation-specific code.
" Also, non-const references can be modified (this means modifying the object that the reference refers to)." - but that's two different things, modifying a reference and modifying an object it refers to, don't you think so?

Comment: @il--ya i don't follow this "references are const pointers" thing, the standard doesn't support that interpretation and it leads to misconceptions like describing references as const when , according to the standard, they are not

Answer (score 2):

Change the line in the header to the following:

```
// REMOVE: extern auto &cParamIDsByAge = cParamIDs.left;
extern const decltype(cParamIDs.left) &cParamIDsByAge;
```

This is forward declaring the reference variable properly. The rest should work as is.

Comment: need a const qualifier

Comment: If it included `const`, then it would include `&` too. You can make it include both `const` and `&` by adding a couple of extra parentheses: `decltype((cParamIDs.left))`

Comment: Check it online: https://godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang341,options:'--std%3Dc%2B%2B11',source:'%23include+%3Cboost/bimap.hpp%3E%0A%0Atypedef+boost::bimap+%3Cint,+int%3E+ParamIDs%3B%0Aextern+const+ParamIDs+cParamIDs%3B%0Aextern+decltype(cParamIDs.left)%26+cParamIDsByAge%3B%0A%0A//+In+my+code+this+inits+the+variable+with+some+data+via+a+function.%0Aconst+ParamIDs+cParamIDs+%7B%7D%3B%0Aauto+%26cParamIDsByAge+%3D+cParamIDs.left%3B')),filterAsm:(directives:!t),version:3

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

In the header file, declare the type of `cParamIDsByAge` without using auto and don't initialize it:

**code.h**

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>

typedef boost::bimap <int, int> ParamIDs;
extern const ParamIDs cParamIDs;

extern const decltype(cParamIDs.left)& cParamIDsByAge;
// or
extern decltype((cParamIDs.left)) cParamIDsByAge;
// or
extern const ParamIDs::left_map& cParamIDsByAge;
```

**code.cpp**

```
#include "code.h"

const ParamIDs cParamIDs {};
auto &cParamIDsByAge = cParamIDs.left;
```

### Solution 2

Use a function instead of a variable:

**code.h**

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>

typedef boost::bimap <int, int> ParamIDs;
extern const ParamIDs cParamIDs;
inline auto& cParamIDsByAge() { return cParamIDs.left; }
```