# Mutable Lvalue Reference of Parameter Passed by const Reference

Tags: c++

I just found an interesting case: I passed an object by `const reference` and still I was able to modify its member (which happens to be an `lvalue reference`). [Following](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebeb83e8c1d2db1a) is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct PersonRef
{
  PersonRef(std::string& name_) : _name(name_) {}
  std::string& _name; // <==== IMPORTANT: it is a reference
};

void testRef(const PersonRef& pr) {
  std::string& name = pr._name; // binding to lvalue reference? How does it even compile?
  name = "changed!";
}

int main() {
  std::string name = "trivial_name";
  PersonRef pr{name};

  std::cout << pr._name << "\n"; // prints: trivial_name
  testRef(pr);
  std::cout << pr._name << "\n"; // prints: changed!
}
```

I used to think that if the parameter is passed by `const ref`, then object is immutable but this doesn't appear to be the case here. Could someone please explain this? Thanks!

Comment: 1) passing by `const &` does not mean that object is immutable, it means that reference has `const` qualifier which will effect overload resolution  2) you never modify its member, you modify a non-const-qualified object referenced by its member; note that even though you are accessing `_name` using `Person const &` it does not adjust type of `_name` to `std::string const &`. If `_name` was a pointer `std::string *` then `const` qualifier would be applied to pointer so it'll became `std::string * const`, but references are not rebindable by default so `std::string & const` does nothing.

Comment: ok, so perhaps, the fundamental questions are:
1) If I am accessing `_name` by `const PersonRef&` why its type is not adjusted to `const std::string&`. This is what I had expected.
2)  what do you mean by _std::string & const does nothing_ ? if I declare `_name` to be `const std::string& `, this code doesn't compile as I can't ignore its `cost-ness` while binding it to `non-const lvalue reference` inside the function.

Comment: Accessing class members through a const-qualified reference does add const qualifier to class members. But `_name` member is a reference that is it has one level of indirection. Const qualifier is not propagated through that lever of indirection, it applies only directly to class member. That is accessing `_name` yields `std::string & const` and not `std::string const &` as you expect (also you seem be to confused by `const` placement) Since references are not rebindable `std::string & const` behaves exactly the same way as `std::string &`.

Comment: thanks, made a lot of sense! I was confused between `std::string & const` and  `std::string const &`

Comment: [right-to-left / spiral reading order is indeed confusing](https://github.com/guaranteed-to-be-unique/Straight-Declarations/blob/master/Meme.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a different example.

Let's say you have `struct A {int *x;};`.
When accessed through `const A &ref`, `x` would have type `int *const` - a `const` pointer to (non-`const`) `int`.

As you can see, `const` is *not* added recursively to the pointer. It's only added at the top level.

---

Back to your code. Strictly speaking, `const PersonRef& pr` is not a `const` reference. It's a non-`const` reference **to** `const PersonRef`.

(In theory, a `const` reference would be written as `PersonRef &const pr`. But since references are not rebindable to begin with, adding `const` wouldn't do anything, and thus isn't allowed. So technically references are never `const`, even though you can't rebind them.)

The compiler can't add `const`-ness to to `std::string& _name`, since references can't be `const`. And it doesn't add `const`-ness recursively to the referenced type, simply because that's how the language works.

---

If you don't want this behavior, make `std::string& _name` `private` and add a pair of `const` and non-`const` accesors:

```
class PersonRef
{
    std::string &_name;
  public:
    PersonRef(std::string& name_) : _name(name_) {}
    std::string &name() {return _name;}
    const std::string &name() const {return _name;}

};
```

Comment: Ok, so from what I understood:
non-const reference to `const T` should have made 
1) its pointer const, 
2) its non-reference member `const` but 
3) it can't make its reference `const` as `references` are never const
right?

Comment: @aniliitb10 References are not rebindable, that is **they are always const**, therefore const qualifier is omitted.

Comment: yes, thanks, I found a similar question which describes that the references are [inherently const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420780/what-is-a-constant-reference-not-a-reference-to-a-constant). It made a lot of sense when I realized that const-ness of T is not applied recursively!

Answer (score 1):

Note that in `const` member function, the data member `_name` itself will be considered as `const`. This doesn't make any difference on `_name` because it's a reference, which can't be `const`-qualified. (In a sence the reference is always *`const`*, you can't *modify* the reference itself, the reference can't be rebound to other object after initialization.)

On the other hand, the referenced object won't be become `const`, so it's still possible to be modified, `_name` won't become `const std::string&` (reference to `const`).

Similar thing happens on pointer members; in `const` member function they become `const` pointers, but not pointers to `const`; you still could modify the pointed objects if they're non-`const`s from the beginning.