# Why does putting const on the left side of an ampersand valid when referring to a pointer but not on the right?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, this

I was wondering why this line is considered valid:

```
Entity* const & e = this;
```

But this line is not:

```
Entity* & const e = this;
```

What does the ampersand actually doing here? Why is putting const on the left of it valid but not on the right? By the way, these lines are part of a constructor in a class called Entity.

Comment: I' mhesitant to use this as a dupe target but it has the answer and more for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694630/c-const-reference-before-vs-after-type-specifier

Comment: To get a better answer than it's a reference to a pointer, we need to have some more code for context to tell you what the `&` is doing.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420780/what-is-a-constant-reference-not-a-reference-to-a-constant

Comment: if you put the const on the right of the ampersand, it makes the ampersand constant, meaning you cannot change its value. when it is on the left, the pointer is the one that is constant, so you can attribute a value to `e`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does the ampersand actually doing here?

It is a punctuator that that designates a reference type. It is similar to how the asterisk designates a pointer type.

> Why is putting const on the left of it valid but not on the right

Because const qualifier applies to whatever is on the left side of it<sup>1</sup>. And if const is to the right of the ampersand, then the qualifier would apply to the reference. But that is not allowed by the language. Const cannot be applied to a reference (unlike it can be applied to a pointer). Such qualification would be meaningless. References cannot be modified regardless.

There is no such thing as const reference in C++. Although colloquially, it is common to use "const reference" when people actually mean reference to const.

---

<sup>1</sup> Except when the qualifier is the left most token in which case it applies to the right `const T&` is same as `T const &`. All of this applies to volatile as well.

Comment: Might want to edit/clarify this a bit. When i write `const int i = 5` I'm pretty certain its not applying const to the left.

Comment: +1 @Taekahn, there is an exception where the const can be first and then it qualifies the first type, so this should be noted

Comment: @Taekahn Added clarfication.

Answer (score 3):

`Entity* const & e = this;` is a "reference to const pointer to Entity".

`Entity* & const e = this;` would be a "const reference to pointer to Entity", but references can't be `const`<sup>1</sup>, thus you get an error.

---

<sup>1</sup> - Once it's created, you can't "rebind" a reference to make it point to a different object. Because of that, some argue that references "are always const", but it's misleading at least. `std::is_const` returns `false` for references, so formally they are never `const`.

Answer (score 2):

The `this` pointer is declared as follows:

```
Entity* const this
```

which means it is a pointer to the current object, where the value of that pointer itself cannot be modified (i.e. the address that `this` is pointing to cannot be modified).

In the first example, you are declaring a variable called e which is a **reference** to an entity (const) pointer, i.e. a reference to a (non-changing) (pointer) to an entity, which matches the type of **this**.

In the second example, you are declaring a reference to an **entity pointer**, where the value/address of this actual pointer **may** change. The **const** keyword here is not specifying the state of the pointer's address, but is rather specifying that the reference itself will not change, i.e. will not reference a new Entity*.

In fact, as pointed out, the added "const" to qualify a reference will not compile (as it is redundant and makes no sense, references cannot be modified), and therefore the follow is incorrect too:

```
int x = 5;
int& const y = x;
```

Hope this helped!